# ODBC Connection to Access 2007 on WinXP

Tags: windows-xp, odbc, ms-access-2007

Is it possible to have an ODBC connection to a MS Access 2007 database on Windows XP without having any other database engine (i.e. Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0) installed?

I am using the following connection string which works on Windows 7 but not on Windows XP. (There is only *.mdb option in Data Sources (ODBC) control panel in Windows XP and no *.accdb option is there but both exist on Windows 7.):

```
connectionString = "Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ=|DataDirectory|Database1.accdb"
```

Comment: Are you seriously asking if you can somehow magically access data in a format without having the support for accessing that data installed? WTF? Of course you have to have the drivers installed. However, MDB format doesn't require anything new installed, as it's Jet 4, which is installed by default on all versions of Windows since Win2000. If it's ACCDB, you need to install the drivers if A2007 or A2010 is not installed on the machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download drivers: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7554f536-8c28-4598-9b72-ef94e038c891&displaylang=en